# IF condition: Passing first assigned variable as a parameter of a function on second condition

Tags: php

I want to do something like this:

```
if( $a = 'something' && $b = substr( $a, 2 ) )
{
    //do something
}
```

I mean, on an `if` condition, evaluate two conditions, and the second one passing the first assigned `$a` as a parameter to the second condition function `substr()`.

It is just an example, so I don't want answers to this functionality, just generic answers.

The above code throws 'Undefined' `$a`, since `$a` is not still assigned.

I could do the next:

```
if( $a = 'something')
{
    if( $b = substr( $a, 2 ) )
        //do something
    }
}
```

but this will make my code bigger.

Is there any way to achieve something like the first example?

**Edit:**

I don't want to compare. Just assign and ensure that `$a` and `$b` are not null, false, ...

Comment: For starter, it should be if `($a == 'something') && $b == substr( $a, 2 ))`

Comment: You have to use double == otherwise you will assign values and not compare.

Comment: @MarcelBalzer - I don't want to compare. Just assign and ensure that it is not false or empty string, or 0.

Comment: @Leonardo - Same for you.

Comment: Thanks to you all. @deceze is the most generic answer, but I'm grateful for that discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only problem is the wrong precedence of the `&&` and `=` operators. This works just fine:

```
if (($a = 'something') && $b = substr($a, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This way, `$a` is undefined:

```
if ($a = 'something' && $b = substr($a, 2))
```

But if you give the `=` operator priority:

```
if (($a = 'something') && $b = substr($a, 2))
```

It will be set.

Moreover, you can simply write:

```
if( $b = substr( $a = 'something', 2 ) )
```

Comment: You can't simply rewrite it like in your last example assuming that `substr` should not be executed at all if `!$a`.

Comment: @deceze but isn't it `$a` always set  by definition, because we are actually setting it to `something`? [I am not considering the case in which it may be set to a falsy value due to a function call, for instance].

Comment: The last line is the correct answer. I tested with "falsy" values. substr will evaluate to false if it fails. EDIT: "truthy" values will cause it to fail.

Comment: I am very strongly convinced this is only an example. Consider: `if (($foo = bar()) && baz($foo))`. `bar` could return much more complex values than a string and `baz` may not be as forgiving as `substr` on wrong inputs. So while your rewrite may not fail in this limited case, it's not really the same algorithm at all.

Comment: @deceze yes you are right. I guess this is not a topic that has any kind of universal solution, and sacrificing readability // consistency for saving a couple of lines is never the way to go imo [though if you have well known constraints it is very good to take advantage of assign operator and short circuitation].

Answer (score 1):

This question intrigued me along with @moonwave99 answer, so I did some testing with his last answer.

```
if( $b = substr( $a = NULL, 2 ) ) { echo "PASS"; } else { echo "FAIL"; }

FAIL

if( $b = substr( $a = FALSE, 2 ) ) { echo "PASS"; } else { echo "FAIL"; }

FAIL

if( $b = substr( $a = 0, 2 ) ) { echo "PASS"; } else { echo "FAIL"; }

FAIL

if( $b = substr( $a = TRUE, 2 ) ) { echo "PASS"; } else { echo "FAIL"; }

FAIL

if( $b = substr( $a = 233, 2 ) ) { echo "PASS"; } else { echo "FAIL"; }

PASS

if( $b = substr( $a = "SOMETHING", 2 ) ) { echo "PASS"; } else { echo "FAIL"; }

PASS
```

The only way to get it to fail was to pass the Boolean TRUE. But if you are expecting string values, it should fail all Boolean values, zero and NULL and evaluate to true on ints, floats, and string values. (Haven't tested with array, but I suspect it would fail for any non-primitive types). Interesting question.

Comment: *It is just an example, so I don't want answers to this functionality, just generic answers.* - For this particular value and function, yes, there are various ways to do it. However, the algorithm should work regardless of the specifics of what value `$a` is and what function `substr` is.

Comment: Actually the `$a = TRUE` does not pass, because you are extracting the  substr starting from the 3rd character, and a boolean only has one - if you call `substr($a = true, 0)` it will do [though it won't make much sense].

Comment: @deceze is the most correct generic answer, however the question is too vague really. At what point are you minimizing code but it becomes unreasonable to figure out what you were doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [isset()](https://www.php.net/isset) for that.Also keep in mind use `==` or `===` for comparison operations since `=` is assignment operator

```
if( (isset($a) &&  $a == 'something') && (isset($b) && $b == substr( $a, 2 )) )
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Mr.dowvotter do you have a reason.?

Comment: This is simply not what the OP asked for at all.